# I was asked in an interview that . Consider a Scenario where you have instances in different AWS regions what is the best way to communicate by SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**I was asked in an interview that . Consider a Scenario where you have instances in different AWS regions what is the best way to communicate by SSH port 22.**

He said let us say that they are RDS instances

I couldn't find the answer anywhere please Answer my question

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am not understanding your questions, it could have been a trick question as you can't communicate directly with RDS instances via SSH. They are managed for you and you don't have direct access to them.